# Workaround Firefox Update Addons

Tags: java, unit-testing, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I would like to know how to get rid of the many update screens (addons compatibility,....) in firefox, when it was updated. I'm using WebDriver in Java.
It's no problem for me to use a custom firefox profile and I already tried with some custom prefs.js. but with no effect.

Any idea?

Comment: Well as you can see in the answer below this can possibly be a programming questions as it may have a programming solution. Yes I used the java tag because I test with WebDriver in Java.

Comment: Clarity helps avoid closure.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting with a custom profile, all you need to keep in your profile folder are prefs.js, cert8.db, cert_override.txt files. You would require only these. Now for your addons issue, make sure that prefs.js doesn't contain any preference which points to old version for firefox. This will happen if you are creating the firefox profile files using a different version of firefox than the one you are testing with.

Comment: Ok thank you for the hint for the required files. The reason why I want to disable the update extension check is because if an update occurs the user shouldnt need to create a new firefox profile

Answer (score 1):

What about this preference?

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Extensions.checkCompatibility

Also, unless the extensions are needed, try starting in Firefox's 'safe mode' whereby the extensions are disabled altogether, e.g in C#

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary();
binary.StartProfile(profile, "-safe-mode");
```

I know you are in Java, but the StartProfile method exists in the Java bindings as well, and I expect this is what you are after.

Comment: hey, the checkcompatibility preference didnt work, I already tried that. Is there any set back when running firefox in safe mode??

Comment: Are the prefs.js used when starting in safe mode? because I need the SSL-Certificate handling which is written in the prefs.js